# Looking for JQuery OpenViewer for PDF Files

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to find the location of a JavaScript Function that is being used for another site, and Im having trouble locating this function via FireBug.  I can see this in the DOM, but it doesnt provide me with the function.

Here is the site: www.williamsprofessionalpainting.com

Here is the function: OpenViewer

This is simply an onClick Method of an Anchor Tag, which opens up PDF documents.

If someone could help me locate this function, I would greatly appreciate it.

Or, if there is a better JQuery solution, I would actually prefer that option.  I've searched but can't seem to find an alternative.

Comment: chances are it's a custom function or custom plugin that someone built specifically for the site in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the global.js file.  It just wraps window.open() using the path from the anchor as the url.

```
function OpenViewer(path)
{
    if(path != "")
    window.open(path,"SurveyViewer","toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,width=800,height=640,resizable=1");
    else
    alert("NO PATH!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function OpenViewer(path)
{
    if(path != "")
    window.open(path,"SurveyViewer","toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,width=800,height=640,resizable=1");
    else
    alert("NO PATH!");
}
```

using the Chrome Javascript Console.